# what is the suitable number of nodes in elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

If I configured my elasticsearch cluster with the following configuration, and I have to create about 10 indexes, what will be the suitable number of nodes I need  ?

```
index.number_of_shards: 7
index.number_of_replicas: 1
```

Comment: Refer this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24075862/2134604

Answer (score 1):

I would say that depends from how much information you receive. But that is the beauty of elasticsearch, expand a cluster is the easiest thing you have to do and it will balance itself.

If you have 10 indexes, two copies of each (original+replica) and 7 shards for each, your max number of nodes will be 2*10*7=140. Your minimum should be 2 because of the number of replicas. After you do some analysis to the number of records you have and receive daily, you should be able to "guess" what the best cluster size for your system is.

Right now I have a system with 4 data nodes, that has 2 indexes per day (last 2 years), 1 replica per index and a 5shard configuration and everything works smoothly. Oh, I receive about 2 million records per day right now.

Comment: In your cluster, do you have any unassigned shards? what about the average size and complexity of the documents indexed into it?

Comment: @Fanooos, I don't have any unassigned shards, why? My documents are pretty simple, basicaly I only have a collection of logs. Each document have about 0.5Kb and it can have some strings, numbers and some nested data, but nothing very complex.

Maybe it is better for you to try do to some profiling. Get the document average size, the time it takes do to a bulk insert, a simple insert and other operations that would be common on your system